# Replace a Zero with previous value store it

Tags: matlab, csv

I'm trying to replace a zero value with the previous value while storing it in a variable. I imported the csv file as a Numeric Matrix.

[image: Stock_Market is the import csv file]

[image: for example the 0 would be replaced by 30.969999]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code should be something like below:

```
Stocks = Stock_Market;
for i = 2:length(Stocks(:,1))
  if Stocks(i,1)==0
    Stocks(i,1) = Stocks(i-1,1);
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you, I guess I was over thinking it